# How to write custom scala slick column mapping

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

My use case is very simple.

I have wrapper class around string in scala and I want to map it to `String` type in database using my custom scala mapper code (class is 3rd party and I can't modify it.

All examples I found so far referring to `MappedColumnType` which does not seems to exist in Slick 3.

Any help and ideally working examples are appreciated.

Comment: it seems MappedColumnType is indeed supported in slick 3. http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html

Comment: For some reason I do not see it in my classpath. Let me double check my sbt config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be missing the driver api import!

For some reference, have a look at my example here:

https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/blob/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/services/database/DBSchema.scala

```
implicit def powerPlantTypeMapping =
    MappedColumnType.base[PowerPlantType, String](
      powerPlantType => PowerPlantType.toString(powerPlantType),
      powerPlantTypeStr => PowerPlantType.fromString(powerPlantTypeStr)
    )
```

You need to import:

```
import driver.api._
```

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/blob/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/services/database/repository/DBSchema.scala